# i was trying to rebuild my code for my bot but then there are errors coming up i am in the middle of my project so i need quick help

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

```cpp
#include <AFMotor.h>
#include <NewPing.h>
#include <Servo.h>

#define TRIG_PIN A0
#define ECHO_PIN A1
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200
#define MAX_SPEED 190
#define MAX_SPEED_OFFSET 20

NewPing sonar (TRIG_PIN,ECHO_PIN,MAX_DISTANCE);
  
AF_DCMotor motor1(1, MOTOR12_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor2(2, MOTOR12_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor3(3, MOTOR34_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor4(4, MOTOR34_1KHZ);

Servo myservo;
boolean goesForward=fclose;
int distance = 100;
int speedSet = 0;

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(10);
  myservo.write(115);
  delay(2000);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
  int distanceR = 0;
  int distanceL = 0;
  delay (40);

  if (distance <= 15); {
    moveStop();
    delay(100);
    moveForward();
    delay(300);
    moveStop();
    delay(200);
    distanceR = lookRight();
    delay(200);
    distanceL = lookLeft();
    delay(200);

    if (distanceR>=distanceL) {
      turnRight();
      moveStop();
    } else {
      turnLeft();
      moveStop();  
    }}else {
      moveForward();
    }
      distance=readPing();
  }
  
  int lookRight() {
    myservo.write(170);
    delay(500);
    int distance=readPing();
    delay(100);
    myservo.write(115);
    return distance;
    delay(100);
  }

  int readPing() {
    delay(70);
    int cm = sonar.ping_cm();
    if (cm ==) {
      cm=250;
    }
      return cm;
  }

  void moveStop() {
    motor1.run(RELEASE);
    motor2.run(RELEASE);
    motor3.run(RELEASE);
    motor4.run(RELEASE);  
  }

  void moveForward() {
    if (!goesForward) {
      goesFORWARD=true;
      motor1.run(FORWARD);
      motor2.run(FORWARD);
      motor3.run(FORWARD);
      motor4.run(FORWARD);
      for (speedSet=0; speedSet<MAX_SPEED;speedSet+=2) {
        motor1.setSpeed(speed.Set};
        motor2.setSpeed(speed.Set};
        motor3.setSpeed(speed.Set};
        motor4.setSpeed(speed.Set};
        delay(5);
      }
    }
  }

  void moveBackward() {
    goesFORWARD=false;
    motor1.run(BACKWARD);
    motor2.run(BACKWARD);
    motor3.run(BACKWARD);
    motor4.run(BACKWARD);
    for (speedSet=0; speedSet<MAX_SPEED;speedSet+=2) {
      motor1.setSpeed(speed.Set};
      motor2.setSpeed(speed.Set};
      motor3.setSpeed(speed.Set};
      motor4.setSpeed(speed.Set};
      delay(5);
    }
  }

  void moveRight() {
    motor1.run(FORWARD);
    motor2.run(FORWARD);
    motor3.run(BACKWARD);
    motor4.run(BACKWARD);
    delay (500);
    motor1.run(FORWARD);
    motor2.run(FORWARD);
    motor3.run(FORWARD);
    motor4.run(FORWARD);
  }

  void moveRight() {
    motor1.run(BACKWARD);
    motor2.run(BACKWARD);
    motor3.run(FORWARD);
    motor4.run(FORWARD);
    delay (500);
    motor1.run(FORWARD);
    motor2.run(FORWARD);
    motor3.run(FORWARD);
    motor4.run(FORWARD);
  }
```

this is the error code

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows Store 1.8.42.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"
C:\Users\amish\Documents\Arduino\sketch_nov27b\sketch_nov27b.ino: In function 'void loop()':

sketch_nov27b:53:13: error: 'lookLeft' was not declared in this scope
 distanceL = lookLeft();
             ^~~~~~~~

C:\Users\amish\Documents\Arduino\sketch_nov27b\sketch_nov27b.ino:53:13: note: suggested alternative: 'lookRight'

 distanceL = lookLeft();
             ^~~~~~~~
              lookRight

sketch_nov27b:58:1: error: 'turnRight' was not declared in this scope
 turnRight();
 ^~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\amish\Documents\Arduino\sketch_nov27b\sketch_nov27b.ino:58:1: note: suggested alternative: 'lookRight'

 turnRight();
 ^~~~~~~~~
 lookRight

sketch_nov27b:62:1: error: 'turnLeft' was not declared in this scope
 turnLeft();
 ^~~~~~~~

Sketch_nov27b:65:4: error: 'else' without a previous 'if'

   }else

    ^~~~

C:\Users\amish\Documents\Arduino\sketch_nov27b\sketch_nov27b.ino: In function 'int readPing()':

sketch_nov27b:86:10: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

   if(cm==)

          ^

C:\Users\amish\Documents\Arduino\sketch_nov27b\sketch_nov27b.ino: In function 'void moveForward()':

sketch_nov27b:104:1: error: 'goesFORWARD' was not declared in this scope

 goesFORWARD=true;

 ^~~~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\amish\Documents\Arduino\sketch_nov27b\sketch_nov27b.ino:104:1: note: suggested alternative: 'FORWARD'

 goesFORWARD=true;

 ^~~~~~~~~~~

 FORWARD

sketch_nov27b:111:17: error: 'speed' was not declared in this scope

 motor1.setSpeed(speed.Set};

                 ^~~~~

C:\Users\amish\Documents\Arduino\sketch_nov27b\sketch_nov27b.ino:111:17: note: suggested alternative: 'speedSet'

 motor1.setSpeed(speed.Set};

                 ^~~~~

                 speedSet

sketch_nov27b:112:17: error: 'speed' was not declared in this scope

 motor2.setSpeed(speed.Set};

                 ^~~~~

C:\Users\amish\Documents\Arduino\sketch_nov27b\sketch_nov27b.ino:112:17: note: suggested alternative: 'speedSet'

 motor2.setSpeed(speed.Set};

                 ^~~~~

                 speedSet

sketch_nov27b:113:17: error: 'speed' was not declared in this scope

 motor3.setSpeed(speed.Set};

                 ^~~~~

C:\Users\amish\Documents\Arduino\sketch_nov27b\sketch_nov27b.ino:113:17: note: suggested alternative: 'speedSet'

 motor3.setSpeed(speed.Set};

                 ^~~~~

                 speedSet

C:\Users\amish\Documents\Arduino\sketch_nov27b\sketch_nov27b.ino: At global scope:

sketch_nov27b:114:1: error: 'motor4' does not name a type

 motor4.setSpeed(speed.Set};

 ^~~~~~

sketch_nov27b:114:26: error: expected declaration before '}' token

 motor4.setSpeed(speed.Set};

                          ^

Multiple libraries were found for "Servo.h"

 Used: C:\Users\amish\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Servo

 Not used: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\libraries\Servo

exit status 1

'lookLeft' was not declared in this scope

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: the servo part was not working so it came together

Comment: Sort out your code indentation and you will immediately see where the problem is. Try with the autoformat in the IDE.

Comment: thanks a lot...

Comment: You say you need quick help. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is riddled with typographical and basic syntax errors. Such things as using brackets instead of parentheses, semicolons after an `if` meaning it will do nothing, etc.

Sort out your basic syntax errors (hint: autoformat can help you with the indenting to highlight your problems) and you will see where you have gone wrong.

For instance, after autoformatting your code with `astyle` the `moveForward()` function has turned into this mess:

```
 99     if (!goesForward) {
100         goesFORWARD = true;
101         motor1.run(FORWARD);
102         motor2.run(FORWARD);
103         motor3.run(FORWARD);
104         motor4.run(FORWARD);
105 
106         for (speedSet = 0; speedSet < MAX_SPEED; speedSet += 2) {
107             motor1.setSpeed(speed.Set
108         };
109 
110         motor2.setSpeed(speed.Set
111     };
112 
113     motor3.setSpeed(speed.Set
114 };
115 motor4.setSpeed(speed.Set
116 };
117 delay(5);
118 }
119 }
120 }
```

Also, you have no `lookLeft` function - instead you have two `lookRight` functions.  You really should *read* what you've written.